# How to do something when Close (X) button is clicked in JInternalFrame

Tags: java, swing, applet, jinternalframe

I got a assignment to create a `JInternalFrame` that can call mutiple of my applet work (last assignment call `SpherePainter`) and can count how many 'applets' are running inside the `JinternalFrame`.

[the applet are running inside another `JInternalFrame`]

```
public class MyInternalFrame extends JInternalFrame {
static int openFrameCount = 0;
static final int xOffset = 30, yOffset = 30;

public MyInternalFrame() {
    super("SpherePainter #" + (++openFrameCount), 
          true, 
          true, 
          true, 
          true);

    setSize(500,500);
    //Set the window's location.
    setLocation(xOffset*openFrameCount, yOffset*openFrameCount);
    SpherePainterApplet sp = new SpherePainterApplet ();
    sp.init();
    this.add(sp);

}
```

}

I can call the applet with no problem, but I cannot count how many of them are 'actually' running.

My method is to `checkApp++` when one applet is create and `checkApp--` when one is closed.
Is there a way to use listener of closing button (X) or similar?

Comment: Check the JInternalFrame.addInternalFrameListener() method, InternalFrameListener.internalFrameClosing() and InternalFrameListener.internalFrameClosed() listener methods and corresponding tutorial at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/internalframelistener.html.

Comment: it direct to Error 404 page, but I will try your code. Thank you

Comment: Seems like oracle site has some strange rewrite/redirect checks in place, try to go to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html and select the topic "How to Write an Internal Frame Listener" manually.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> "Is there a way to use listener of closing button (X) or similar????"

The appropriate answer seems to be to use an `InternalFrameListener` as Oleg pointed out in the comment. You can see more at [**How to write InternalFrameListeners**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/internalframelistener.html)

```
public class IFrame extends JInternalFrame {

    public IFrame() {
        addInternalFrameListener(new InternalFrameAdapter(){
            public void internalFrameClosing(InternalFrameEvent e) {
                // do something  
            }
        });
    } 
}
```

---

**Side-Note**

> "I got a assignment to create a JInternalFrame that can call mutiple of my applet work"

Whoever gave you this assignment, tell them to read [**Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets**](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/) and possibly even [**The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice). IMO it seems like a useless nonsense assignment, if the requirements are how you described.

Comment: Thank you, this was surprisingly hard information to come by.